# Dropping and Restoring PostGreSql constraints using C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, constraints

I've read that **PostGreSql** doesn't allow you to disable constraint checks.  You have to drop and recreate them.

I'm trying to **temporarily drop the constraint using C#, while I restore the database.  Then re-enable the constraints.**  Is there a way to fetch the current constraints and "save" it before dropping them.  And some how restore them later?

If needed I can save the constraints in C# code, then reconstruct a query to restore it.  But I'm new to PostGreSql so I have no idea how to get a list of the constraints in a way I can use to restore later on.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Postgres [system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalogs.html) to get list of check constraints (for all tables in `public` schema in the below example):

```
create table example (id int, val int check (val > 100), str text check (str <> ''));

select nspname schema_name, relname table_name, conname con_name, consrc con_source
from pg_constraint t
join pg_class c on t.conrelid = c.oid
join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
where contype = 'c' and nspname = 'public';

 schema_name | table_name |     con_name      |    con_source     
-------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------
 public      | example    | example_str_check | (str <> ''::text)
 public      | example    | example_val_check | (val > 100)
(2 rows)
```

Having this dataset you can generate appropriate statements to drop and restore the constraints:

```
alter table public.example drop constraint example_str_check;
alter table public.example drop constraint example_val_check;

alter table public.example add constraint example_str_check check ((str <> ''::text));
alter table public.example add constraint example_val_check check ((val > 100));
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  It was very helpful.